# How do I eliminate irrelevant "Content overflows the viewport" WARNINGs using FOP?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an `fo` file which I use to generate PDF files using FOP. My problem is that whenever I use FOP it fills up the log with warnings such as this:

```
[o.a.fop.events.LoggingEventListener] Content overflows the viewport of an fo:block-container in block-progression direction by 4841 millipoints. Content will be clipped. (See position 588:77)
```

My problem is that I know that content overflows that's why I used `overflow="hidden"` in my template:

```
<fo:block-container overflow="hidden" height="${rowHeight}">
```

so this is working as intended. How do I eliminate these unnecessary warnings?

Comment: I think you would need to post how you are calling FOP in order to recommend how to establish a null logger. BAT file/SH script? Java API?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I found it when trying to find the solution for myself and thought this might be useful to someone else:

In Windows Powershell:
.\fop -q test5.xml test-5.pdf 2> Out-Null

In Linux Bash:
fop -q test5.xml test-5.pdf 2> /dev/null

Comment: This is so old I don't even remember what Apache Fop is doing 